# Vagrant shell provision: Ubuntu commands

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

A friend of mine shared a script for doing a shell provision with Vagrant.

This is my first time using vagrant and I am also not ubuntu or linux user.

The script was causing the Vagrant provision to error out on grub. I isolated it to these two lines in particular.

```
apt-get update  -y -qq >/dev/null
apt-get upgrade -y -qq >/dev/null
```

After doing some research I got a decent idea of what apt is, what the -y and -qq options do, but I haven't been able to figure out what '>/dev/null' is doing.

I had to remove the '>/dev/null' from both lines to get the provisioning to work.

Can someone please explain to me what '>/dev/null' does and why it may have been causing an error relating to grub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>/dev/null` discards the output to the black hole.

In your case, I think it is a better practice to discard both stdout and stderr in automation tasks, instead of using `-qq` with `apt-get`. For example

`apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y > /dev/null 2>&1`

> NOTE: `2>&1` means redirect stderr to stdout, while stdout will be discarded as it is redirect to the black hole.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, we don't bother with redirection on provisioning, at least you can see what's going on. So don't feel like you need to have the >/dev/null on at all.